# Get Unique numbers of count with multiple filter criteria in excel sheet without using ctrl + shift + enter (CSE)

Tags: php, excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, phpexcel

Below formula is working fine for me with `ctrl + shift + enter`(CSE) in Excel sheet.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(IF(($sheet11.$E$2:$E$285=A5)*(IF(NOT($J$3="All");$sheet11.$D$2:$D$285=$J$3;$sheet11.$D$2:$D$285<>""))*(IF(NOT($M$3="All");$sheet11.$C$2:$C$285=$M$3;$sheet11.$C$2:$C$285<>""));$sheet11.$A$2:$A$285);$sheet11.$A$2:$A$285)>0))
```

I am getting **unique numbers of total count** as per **date**(A5) with selected filter in column **type1**($j$3) and **type2**($M$3) in excel sheet.

Is there any way to apply same without using `ctrl + shift + enter` (CSE)?

i.e: in sheet 11 I have column E: Date and D: type 1 and C: type 2 and A: orders

in sheet 2 I want numbers unique count as per date + type1(if filter applied) + type2(if filter applied)

Is there any way to apply the same formula or different formula without using CSE?[image]

[image]

Comment: First question: why does it matter?

Comment: @Rory I am implemented this using phpexcel in PHP but its not working in google sheet i want compatible it with all sheet(i.e : excel,openoffice & google sheet) also when i tried to open sheet it repaired every time it's not good

Comment: So what does this have to do with Excel-VBA? Also, you should probably add all of that **extremely relevant** information to your question!

Comment: @Rory Please check as i added relevant details now is it possible to help me out here